# Typewriter effect in Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html

I looked at a few examples on how to make a typewriter effect but my solution doesn't seem to work.I have three sentences that I want to loop forever and have them typed letter by letter to get that typewriter effect. Here is my code:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">  
      <title>Кухнята на Дани</title>   
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script> <!--required for the next script-->
        <!--some other javascript that requires the JQuery code above-->
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function typeWriter(){
            var flag=0;
            while(flag=0)
                  {
                    var s1 = "sentence1";
                    var s2 = "sentence2";
                    var s3 = "sentence3";
                    var s = "";
                    var i = 0;
                    document.getElementById("sub-element").innerHTML=s;
                    for(i=0; i<s1.length; i++)
                        {
                            s=s1.charAt(i);
                            document.getElementById("sub-element").innerHTML = document.getElementById("sub-element").innerHTML+s;
                            setTimeout(typeWriter, 50);
                        }
                    s="";
                    document.getElementById("sub-element").innerHTML=s;
                    for(i=0; i<s2.length;i++)
                        {
                            s=s2.charAt(i);
                            document.getElementById("sub-element").innerHTML = document.getElementById("sub-element").innerHTML+s;
                            setTimeout(typeWriter, 50);
                        }
                    s="";
                    document.getElementById("sub-element").innerHTML=s;
                    for(i=0; i<s3.length;i++)
                        {
                            s=s3.charAt(i);
                            document.getElementById("sub-element").innerHTML = document.getElementById("sub-element").innerHTML+s;
                            setTimeout(typeWriter, 50);
                        }
                    s="";                        
                  } 
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload = "typeWriter()">
      <header>        
      <!--header and navigation stuff here-->
      </header>             
        <section id="home">
         <div class="container">        
       <h1>Кухнята на Дани</h1>
                <p id="sub-element"></p> <!--the text will appear in this paragraph-->                      
         </div>
     </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Due to some reason, the Javascript code won't work. 
Excuse me for my code. I know it's too long but I decided to include everything that might be important.

Comment: The code kinda works, but the results of the DOM manipulations can't be seen before the script is finished, and you're seeing all the changes made at once. You need a [timer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval), and no `while`loop.

Comment: Try out Typed.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 <section id="home">
            <div class="container">                     
                <h1>Кухнята на Дани</h1>
                <p id="newmsg"></p> <!--the text will appear in this paragraph-->                               
            </div>
        </section>
```

Javascript code

```
var im = 0, ij=0;
    var txtarray = ['sentence1', 'sentence2', 'sentence3'];
    var speed = 100;

    function typeWriter() {
      if (im < txtarray[ij].length) {
        document.getElementById("newmsg").innerHTML += txtarray[ij].charAt(im);
        im++;
        setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
      }
      else{
        setTimeout(repeatt, 1000);
      }
    }
     typeWriter();

    function repeatt() {
        document.getElementById("newmsg").innerHTML = "";
        im=0;
        if(ij < txtarray.length-1){
            ij++;
        }
        else{
            ij = 0;
        }
        typeWriter();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a while loop, meaning that even though you are appending one letter at a time it happens too fast (and in the same render frame) and thus you dont see the type effect.

You need to execute the function on some time interval, for example

```
setInterval(appendLetter, 200)
```

Which will execute appendLetter function every 200 ms and there you can have your chars append logic.

```
const text = "some text to loop"
let charIndex = 0;

function appendLetter() {
    document.getElementById("aaa").innerHTML = text.substr(0, charIndex)
    charIndex++;
    if(charIndex > text.length) charIndex = 0;
}

setInterval(appendLetter, 250);
```